# Delphi AnsiStartsStr missing

Tags: delphi, vcl

If i use AnsiStartsStr in delphi vcl have the error:
undeclared identifier

I allready installed the fix pack but it didn't help.
How can i fix this?
I tried:

```
if AnsiStartsStr('CONNECTINFO<-+^+->', socket.receivetext) then
    begin;

    end;
```

Comment: Use strutils or ansistrings depending on your version/string type.

Comment: If that doesn't make any sense, see [this](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Programs_and_Units#Unit_References_and_the_Uses_Clause).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such a situation the first task is to look in the documentation. There are actually two functions with that name. They are documented here:

- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.AnsiStrings.AnsiStartsStr
- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.StrUtils.AnsiStartsStr

The title of the documentation tells you the unit you need. Either

- System.AnsiStrings or
- System.StrUtils

So you need to add the appropriate unit to your uses clause. I cannot tell for sure which function you need.

If you have problems searching the documentation try the advice here: [How can I search for Delphi documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403628/how-can-i-search-for-delphi-documentation) Of course you should just be able to click in the unrecognised identifier and press F1.

Comment: The docs does not seem to mention `ansistrings.AnsiStartsStr` which really work on ansi strings.

Comment: @Sertac they are documented: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.AnsiStrings. But the code in the question operates on string rather than AnsiString.

Comment: I don't think so. TCustomWinSocket.ReceiveText is ansi, at least in XE2.

Comment: @sertac Really that's pretty odd. Did they just forget to update those components for Unicode?

Comment: If you ask me, the docs too. F1 help should include the alternative.

Comment: The VCL socket components do not support Unicode. I co-wrote an article about that: http://lebeausoftware.org/articles/bcbj_vol13_num2.3.pdf