# Access the current value of a TScrollBar in delphi

Tags: delphi, scrollbar

I am using  TScrollBar component, maybe I'm being stupid, but I can find a way to just get the value out, for example:

```
 myVal := TForm1.ScrollBar1.getval()
```

Could someone please tell me the command for this please?

Comment: Have you seen [`Position`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TScrollBar.Position) property :) ?

Comment: Knew I was being stupid, I though that was about its position on the form! Ill look at that, thanks for your help :)

Comment: You should make sure you know how to find the documentation. If you know about the docs then you'll be able to work all this stuff out for yourself: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TScrollBar  and   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403628/

Comment: I was using the documentation, I was just looking for a something like "Value".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "value" of a scroll bar is represented by the *position* of the scroll thumb along the bar. Thus, you should read the [`Position` property](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TScrollBar.Position).