# IF statement for MessageDlg Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

How do I use an if statement to get the status of a button that was clicked in a `MessageDlg'?

Heres my code:

```
if MessageDlg('Message',mtError,[mbYesNoCancel],0) = No
    then ShowMessage('Message2');
```

I saw my IT teacher write something like this a while ago, but I don't remember the syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Dialogs.MessageDlg) says:

> MessageDlg returns the value of the button the user selected. The
>   following table lists the TMsgDlgBtn values for each type of button
>   that can appear in the message box, and the corresponding value that
>   is returned if the user selects that button:

```
TMsgDlgBtn Value    Corresponding return value
mbOK                mrOk
mbCancel            mrCancel
mbYes               mrYes
mbNo                mrNo
mbAbort             mrAbort
mbRetry             mrRetry
mbIgnore            mrIgnore
mbAll               mrAll
mbNoToAll           mrNoToAll
mbYesToAll          mrYesToAll
mbClose             mrClose
```

So you need to test for `mrNo`.

I do recommend that you learn [where to find documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403628/) to make your life easier.