# Where do I find API about Tool Palette in Delphi XE6?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

I am a new developer in delphi, use Delphi XE6. I want to know the attribute about one component quickly, the problem is where can i find related api about component in tool palette? Thanks!

Comment: Related: [How can I search for Delphi documentation?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21403628/33732)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, I think the best way to get a sense of a component is to add it to your form, then select it, and check out its attributes in the Object Inspector.

An alternative is to reference the class in question (say, `TButton`) in your code, and place the cursor somewhere in the class name, and invoke the Help (press `F1`) to read up on the class and its members.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I followed your second method to get more information about class,the Helper always displayed page fo 'Code Editor', but not something related the class. Well, how do Help shows the page just like what you say.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy's comment may offer more direct help in getting what you're after. You can also try ctrl-clicking a class name to bring up its source, but I think your results may vary depending on your license level.