# Can I remove parts of the online help I'm not interested in?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe6

When I press F1 I sometimes get the correct info, but often I get a completely unrelated subject in the C++ namespace.

I would be happy if I was able to completely remove all of the C++ help.

I know there is no out-of-the-box solution and embarcadero just says it'd cannot be done: http://codeverge.com/embarcadero.delphi.ide/how-to-remove-c++-and-fmx-related-topi/1059028 
https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=445069
http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/37562

**Is there a way to remove help subjects that I'm not interested in?**

BTW I'm using Delphi XE2 and Delphi XE6.

Comment: Before the last major rewrite, you used to be able to do so by unregistering the help (with h2reg.exe -u), tweaking the contents of h2reg.ini to comment out the parts you didn't want, and then reregistering the help. However, looking at the current h2reg.ini file in XE5 and XE6, it doesn't appear that the documentation is broken down into the granular level any longer that would allow you to remove things like C++ and/or FMX.

Comment: It's usually best to use websearch on the online docs. You get better hits: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403628/how-can-i-search-for-delphi-documentation