# How to rename a Form Name in Delphi XE7?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I am working on a multiple-device application in Embarcadero Delphi XE7.
Being new to delphi I would like to know how (if possible) can I rename a Form's Name.
e.g. TForm3 to something like frmCustomer.

Comment: from the Object Inspector - Form - Name?

Comment: Yes RBA, in the Object Inspector I can change the File Name but the Form Name is read-only.

Comment: At design time all the properties of the form can be edited.

Comment: Thank you RBA, indeed when in code view Form Name is read only. But when in Design is it editable.

Comment: Given how basic a question this is, you will most likely have more of them.  To that end, this may be helpful for you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403628/how-can-i-search-for-delphi-documentation

Answer (score 2):

You can change it from the Delphi Object Inspector - [official documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Basic_customization_of_the_main_form_(IDE_Tutorial)) on how to customize the main form of an application.

Answer (score 0):

You got me a bit confused. You want to rename a class name (TForm3) to frmCustomer. A defacto standard is to prefix all classes with a "T", like TfrmCustomer. Never have a class named frmCustomer, use that for the instance instead (here form3 -> frmCustomer). Generally it's a very good idea to be strict about renaming all controls. Makes things a whole lot easier to maintain.

I prefer to use the built in refactoring (shift-ctrl-e) while having the cursor stand in the """thing" you want renamed, e.g. TForm3. That way the name, that be a class, method or attribute, is changed throughout the project.

I can furthermore recommend you install GExperts which, among many good features, have one to name the components while you place them.