# Signaling between threads in Delphi from Java Code

Tags: java, multithreading, delphi

```
package org.helioviewer.viewmodel.view.jp2view.concurrency;

/**
 * Very simple way of signaling between threads. Has no sense of ownership and
 * thus any thread can signal or wait for a signal. In general it is not a
 * problem if many different threads call the signal method, but only one thread
 * should be calling the waitForSignal method, since there is no way to tell
 * which thread will be woken up.
 * 
 * @author caplins
 * 
 */
public class BooleanSignal {

    /** Signal flag */
    private volatile boolean isSignaled;

    /**
     * Default constructor. Assigns the initial value of the isSignaled flag.
     * 
     * @param _intitialVal
     */
    public BooleanSignal(boolean _intitialVal) {
        isSignaled = _intitialVal;
    }

    /**
     * Used to wait for a signal. Waits until the flag is set, then it resets
     * the flag and returns. The waiting thread can be interrupted and that
     * exception is thrown immediately.
     * 
     * @throws InterruptedException
     */
    public synchronized void waitForSignal() throws InterruptedException {
        while (!isSignaled)
            this.wait();
        isSignaled = false;
    }

    public synchronized void waitForSignal(long timeout) throws InterruptedException {
        while (!isSignaled) {
            this.wait(timeout);
            isSignaled = true;
        }

        isSignaled = false;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the isSignaled flag and wakes up one waiting thread. Doesn't bother
     * to notifyAll since the first thread woken up resets the flag anyway.
     */
    public synchronized void signal() {
        isSignaled = true;
        this.notify();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the signal state.
     * 
     * @return Current signal state
     */
    public synchronized boolean isSignaled() /* throws InterruptedException */{
        /*
         * if(Thread.interrupted()) throw new InterruptedException();
         */
        return isSignaled;
    }
};
```

I would like to signaling between threads using Delphi. I have a sample from Java. How can I convert this code to Delphi or how can I signaling between threads.

I couldn't call thread in another thread directly. So I don't know how to do this in Delphi?

Comment: Use `TEvent` or `TSimpleEvent`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan are there any documentations your suggested?

Comment: [TSimpleEvent](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SyncObjs.TSimpleEvent).

Comment: [TEvent](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SyncObjs.TEvent)  Also take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403628/how-can-i-search-for-delphi-documentation