# What is the use of NEXTGEN compiler conditional?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

While working on a project we were having 4000+ warnings.
To remove some of those I found one compiler Directive as `NEXTGEN`.

After Using this directive I found that there is a much more minimize in the warnings to 257.

I want to know if we have any issues in using the compiler directive. Are there any drawback of this directive for my windows application.
I am using `Delphi 10`.

on Site of Embarcadero I found very less information.

Can anyone tell me something about the same?

Comment: I typed **docwiki nextgen** into google and the first hit documented this conditional. I suggest that you read this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403628/how-can-i-search-for-delphi-documentation

Comment: Time to roll up yer sleeves and fix those warnings I would say. How depends on what exactly they are about though.

Comment: Surely you have an answer to this question now?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Delphi's `NEXTGEN` conditional symbol marks the next-generation ARC compilers. The Windows and OSX compilers are not `NEXTGEN` compilers. The iOS and Android compilers are `NEXTGEN`. Initial release of Linux compiler in 10.2 Tokyo had `NEXTGEN` defined, but since 10.3 Rio it does not.

Any code compiled for Windows that is marked with `NEXTGEN` will be ignored in current compilers.

See [Conditional symbols](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Conditional_compilation_(Delphi)):

> Defined for compilers (such as the Delphi mobile compilers) that use
> "next-generation" language features, such as 0-based strings.
> *New* in XE4/iOS

**Update: 10.4 Sydney**

`NEXTGEN` symbol has been removed from all compilers, along with `AUTOREFCOUNT` and `WEAKINSTREF` symbols.

Comment: Minor nit: Directives are commands to the compiler such as {$D+} or {$WARN xxxx OFF}. Compiler defined conditionals are not "directives", rather they're used for conditional directives {$IF Defined(xxxx)} or {$IFDEF xxxx}, where xxxx can be NEXTGEN

Comment: From 10.3 NEXTGEN is not defined for Linux anymore.

Comment: @ToonKrijthe Thanks for the reminder. I updated the answer.

Comment: In 10.4, NEXTGEN is no longer defined for the iOS and Android compilers.  Embarcadero has decided to go with a "unified" model for all of its compilers, so all of the NEXTGEN features have been turned off, and all of the pre-NEXTGEN features that were turned off for mobile have been turned back on.

Answer (score 3):

The [`NEXTGEN`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Conditional_compilation_(Delphi)) conditional symbol is defined by the compiler. It is defined, for instance, for the mobile compilers that use ARC. It is not defined for the traditional Windows and Mac OS compilers.

You must not define it in your code. You are compiling your code with a traditional compiler, not a `NEXTGEN` compiler. Whatever is responsible for these compiler warnings, defining `NEXTGEN` is not the solution.