# How to Unindent a block of code in Delphi XE3?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

I am using Delphi XE3. Is there a way to unindent a block of codes? I check the edit menu and cannot find such an option.

Comment: Might I be so impertinent to suggest that you read this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403628/how-can-i-search-for-delphi-documentation which will prove useful to you in the future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For indenting and outdenting a block, you can use the following shortcuts:

- <kbd>TAB</kbd> (indent), <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> (outdent)
- <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> (indent), <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> (outdent)
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> (indent), <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> (outdent)

Not all versions of Delphi support all of these different options. You will, obviously, have to use ones that work for your version.

This information can be found in the documentation:

- XE3: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Default_Keyboard_Shortcuts
- Tokyo: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Default_Keyboard_Shortcuts