# Does instruction myVar is TMyObj can work if myVar is nil?

Tags: delphi

Does the instruction `myVar is TMyObj` can work if `myVar` is **nil**? I don't know  how the **is** is performed internally

Comment: Do you know how to find documentation? Perhaps I can suggest you visit this topic https://stackoverflow.com/q/21403628/505088

Comment: seems simple enough to test this yourself with a few lines of code

Comment: @Guido spot checks don't prove something always to be so, hence documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of `is` is available in the system unit.

```
function _IsClass(const Child: TObject; Parent: TClass): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (Child <> nil) and Child.InheritsFrom(Parent);
end;
```

Though, it is not 100% reliable because there is some compiler magic surrounding the `is` operator.

Amongs other, the following :

```
var
  vWin : TWinControl;
begin
  vWin := TWinControl(TControl.Create(nil));
  if vWin is TWinControl then
    ShowMessage('The shouldn''t be true!!!');
  vWin.Free;
end;
```

Gets optimised to (at least in Seattle)

```
var
  vWin : TWinControl;
begin
  vWin := TWinControl(TControl.Create(nil));
  if vWin <> nil then
    ShowMessage('The shouldn''t be true!!!');
  vWin.Free;
end;
```

Which doesn''t give the result one could expect.

Note : I'm not pretending here that `vWin := TWinControl(TControl.Create(nil))` is a valid operation.

Comment: I don't care for this answer. That is actually not the implementation of is. That's the part for object references. But there are also interfaces to consider. And then there's the magic. A good answer here refers to the documentation.

Comment: I think otherwise. IMO The optimization in this case is open for discussion, vWin clearly does NOT point to a TWinControl object, so the is operator should return False, where the optimized code just checks for assignment. I learned something.

Comment: @H.Hasenack The optimisation assume a TWinControl variable will always contains a TWinControl or nil... something I agree on. It is totally fair to consider assigning a TControl in a TWinControl an invalid operation. Though, I don't remember reading any official statement in the documentation to that regard...

Comment: @Ken, exactly. Thats what I learned! Its the choice the optimizer makes. Now I wonder what happens if you turn optimization off... Optimization on/off should NOT change the way the code works, but it might have an effect here. (didn't test)

Comment: @H.Hasenack Optimization should not change DEFINED behavior...  but it is free to alter any undefined behavior. So, if assigning a non TWincontrol to a TWinControl variable is considered "undefined behavior", the optimization is entirely legitimate.

Comment: @Ken, as I said before, you are right. If I find the time, I'll just try it out to satisfy my curiosity :p

Answer (score 10):

It works if `myVar` is of type `TMyObj` or a descendant, but returns false if the object is nil.

See [The is Operator](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Class_References#The_is_Operator): (emphasis mine)

> The is operator, which performs dynamic type checking, is used to verify the actual runtime class of an object. The expression:
>
> ```
> object is class
> ```
>
> returns True if object is an instance of the class denoted by class or one of its descendants, and False otherwise. (**If object is nil, the result is False.**) If the declared type of object is unrelated to class -- that is, if the types are distinct and one is not an ancestor of the other -- a compilation error results.