# In delphi what is the status/scope of a method declared before the private/public/protected keywords

Tags: class, delphi, methods, scope

In delphi what is the status/scope of a method declared before the private/public/protected keywords. see below

```
type

TMyForm = class(TForm)
Procedure test();
private
...
public
...
protected
...
end;
```

Comment: This is explained in the documentation. Do you know how to find the documentation?

Comment: If not then this topic will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403628/how-can-i-search-for-delphi-documentation

Comment: I am sure this is `published` somewhere in the documentation.

Comment: @GuidoG Unless the `{$M-}` documentation is `public`

Answer (score 6):

Every time you have a question about the Delphi language or RTL, you should consult the official documentation. In this case, the section named [Visibility of Class Members](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Classes_and_Objects_(Delphi)#Visibility_of_Class_Members) on [Classes and Objects](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Classes_and_Objects_(Delphi)) contains the following information:

> Members at the beginning of a class declaration that do not have a specified visibility are by default **published**, provided the class is compiled in the {$M+} state or is derived from a class compiled in the {$M+} state; otherwise, such members are **public**.

So, for instance, in a class derived directly from `TObject`, any such members are `public`. In a class derived from `TPersistent`, which includes all components (and therefore all controls), they are `published`.