# Is it possible to declare a global var with an initial value?

Tags: delphi

Maybe I miss something, but is their a way to declare a global var in Delphi with an Initial value?

```
var MyGlobalVar: integer := 16;
```

This not work (but do work when the var is inlined in the code)

Comment: There is a difference (why?) between the syntax used for global variable initialization and local inline variable initialization. The global one uses "=" as assignment operator, the local inline one uses ":=" as assignment operator.

Comment: (Small) part of the answer: global variables with default values have been part of the language "forever", while inline variable declarations were introduced only a year or two ago. Also, notice that the global variable expression must be a constant expression, while the value given to a new inline-declared variable can be given by any (runtime) expression.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403628/how-can-i-search-for-delphi-documentation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. From [the documentation on variables](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Variables_(Delphi)):

> Global variables can be initialized at the same time they are declared, using the syntax:
>
> ```
> var identifier: type = constantExpression;
> ```
>
> where `constantExpression` is any constant expression representing a value of type `type`.

In your case,

```
var MyGlobalVar: Integer = 16;
```

Comment: arf didn't catch the = instead of := ! thanks Adreas